# Object for JSON Payload to be map using Promise function with Callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have a JSON payload that looks like

```
{
    "name": "Reports",
    "subject": "Monthly Reports",
    "attachments":[
        { "attachment":{
            "name": "Month1.pdf",
            "type": "application/pdf",
            "path": "http://example.com/Month1.pdf"
        }
        },
        {"attachment":{
            "name": "Month2.pdf",
            "type": "application/pdf",
            "path": "http://example.com/Month2.pdf"
        }
        }]
}
```

And I want to take the attachment object part received information from the JSON post request and convert the file in the path to base64 format using a promise function which will allow for it to loop through the attachment object for each like the following which is in TypeScript:

**NB:** No looping has been done as I don't know how to achieve this but there should be a for each loop

```
app.post('/send', (req, res) => {
let data = req.body;

function getMonthlyReport() : Promise<object> {
    let blob = request({
        method: 'GET',
        encoding: null,
        uri: data.attachment.path   //http://example.com/Month1.pdf
    }, (err, resp, file)=> {
        let encoded = file.toString('base64');
        // And get the result outside the function which be base64encoded string for each attachment
    });
 }
```

And be able to map it like this outside the function with an await function

```
let attachmentPayload = await Object.keys(data.attachment.path)
    .map(k => ({
        "name":data.attachment.name[k],           // Name from payload
        "type": data.attachment.type[k],          // Type from payload
        "content": encoded  //base64encoded string from promise callback       
}));
```

This is just an example of what I'm trying to achieve using promise functions as I want the information to populate first before move onto the rest of the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be close to what you're looking for; modify as necessary:

```
interface Attachment {
    attachment: {
        name: string;
        type: string;
        path: string;
    }
}
interface InlineAttachment {
    name: string;
    type: string;
    content: string;
}
interface Payload {
    name: string;
    subject: string;
    attachments: Attachment[];
}
interface InlinedPayload {
    name: string;
    subject: string;
    attachments: InlineAttachment[];    
}

app.post('/send', async (req, res) => {
    let data: Payload = req.body;

    function getMonthlyReport(att: Attachment) : Promise<InlineAttachment> {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            let blob = request({
                method: 'GET',
                encoding: null,
                uri: att.attachment.path   //http://example.com/Month1.pdf
            }, (err, resp, file)=> {
                if (err) {
                    reject(err);
                } else {
                    let encoded = file.toString('base64');
                    resolve({
                        name: att.attachment.name,
                        type: att.attachment.type,
                        content: encoded
                    });
                }
            });    
        });
     }

     let inlinedData: InlinedPayload = {
        name: data.name,
        subject: data.subject,
        attachments: await Promise.all(data.attachments.map(getMonthlyReport))
     };
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much. You layered everything so well. I was able to make it work.